# QGIS 3.32 and printing colored text

Tags: pyqgis, printing, color

I spent time looking for a solution but found none. Most were dated from years ago.

If I am in QGIS using the Python console and Python editor how then do I get text to print in various colors or with underscores or italics?

My first find was to install colorama.  I tried that and it prints very odd characters and even then only prints the first word in a string in the selected color.

Is this because I 'can't' print to the console in color?

Is it because the version of python (3.9 I believe with 3.32.1 of QGIS)?

Is it because this cannot be done with code interactively with the python console?

I really do not see a way to solve this!

Any guidance or solutions?

I really do find it amazing that Python does not inherently understand this.  Or maybe I am overlooking the obvious!

Comment: @PolyGeo stop closing questions by default please, you are ruining this community by alienating new users. It makes no sense at all to *require* "code" for this question.

Comment: Where are you printing to? The Python console or the protocol?

Comment: @bugmenot123 The asker has clearly already tried to write some code because they said "My first find was to install colorama. I tried that and it prints very odd characters and even then only prints the first word in a string in the selected color."  However, they have not presented that.  Every Q&A here is a learning opportunity for the community and encouraging askers to present their coding efforts on questions about writing code is the intention here.  As per the [Tour] this question would benefit from asking a single question too.

Comment: Yes they tried something that won't work so that is absolutely irrelevant to the question which is "how to print colored text to the QGIS Python console". As per the tour the is no anal rule that "every question that is in any way related to programming has to contain a piece of code regardless of the context" but you can find e.g. that we "aim to foster collaboration within a safe and welcoming community rooted in kindness, cooperation and mutual respect". Abusing moderator power to close questions because you feel like they aren't perfect is abusive.

Comment: I am trying to print to the results area within the python window set. The one just above the console.